# Why is my for loop and while loop not working well?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

Hi I'm trying to make my program so user will enter days of the week and result should come out as " Monday --> M y" "Tuesday --> T y" i want it to give me first and last letter of the day but when I do my code its just giving me input that was entered last for all of them. here is my code

```
strings = []
user_input = ""
for days in range (7):
user_input = input("Enter a first name. Enter END to stop the program..  ")
strings.append(user_input)

print(strings)

str = 0
while ( str <= 7):
last_str_1st_char = user_input[0]
last_str_2st_char = user_input[0]
last_str_3st_char = user_input[0]
last_str_4st_char = user_input[0]
last_str_5st_char = user_input[0]
last_str_6st_char = user_input[0]
last_str_7st_char = user_input[len(user_input) - 1]
str = str + 1

print("Monday --->",last_str_1st_char, "Tuesday--->",last_str_2st_char, "Wendsday--->", last_str_3st_char,"Thursday--->",last_str_4st_char, "Friday--->",last_str_5st_char "Saturday--->",last_str_6st_char "Sunday--->", last_str_7st_char )
```

Comment: you probably want to iterate ``strings``, otherwise its no wonder you always get the last input, because you're working with ``user_input``.

Comment: Don't post unindented Python code. Make the effort to post code that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> day = 'Monday'
>>> day[0] + ' ' + day[-1]
M y
```